# Pass every element of a large list in R to a Function

Tags: r, r-s4, r-sp

In `R`, Let's say I have a `LargeList` called `l` with 200 elements, each of them is an `S3 dataframe` with 1000 - 10000 rows, named `PersonXXX`.

Now I want to pass every element (which is every `PersonXXX`) in `l` into a function called `fungeo(data.frame)`. For which each of the `fungeo(PersonXXX)` will produce another `S4:SpatialPointDataFrame`. By brute force, I can do `p.XXX = fungeo(PersonXXX)` 200 times, but it seems not intuitive. So, I attempted to write a for loop which looks like:

```
p[[1]]<- 0
for (i in 1: 200){
  p[[i]]<-fungeo(l[[i]])
}
```

which have two problems. First of all, it actually never ran. I keep getting this error message:

```
   Error in p[[i]] <- fungeo(l[[i]]) : 
  more elements supplied than there are to replace
```

Two, I want to get my new Largelist of S4 dataframe with each element named consistently with the personID, let's say `p.XXX` is the S4 transformation of the simple S3 DataFrame `PersonXXX`.

Is there any way I can do that? Any help will be incredibly helpful!

Comment: Try `p <- lapply(s, fungeo)`.

Comment: learn about lapply, apply, sapply. Very basic and important.

Comment: @KarstenW. This was awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try either the "apply" family function
or "map" function from "purrr" package which should do the same job but the latter one could be much faster when working with large dataset

```
lapply(s, fungeo)
map(s,fungeo)
```